# Unable to install Tensorflow in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to install TensorFlow in my PyCharm IDE, but I have been struggling for over 3 days without success.

Do I need Anaconda in order to install TensorFlow? If yes, then how do I get it for an earlier version of python? I can only get it for python 3.9, which I heard isn't compatible with TensorFlow yet.

Every time I try to install TensorFlow it says:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.4 

ERROR: No matching distribution found for Tensorflow
```

Note: I have already tried in PyCharm going to the Python interpreter and installing 2.4.0 it keeps giving me the same error as always.

Comment: Tensorflow doesn't support Python 3.9 yet. Install 64-bit Python 3.8 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install **Anaconda** in order to install **Tensorflow**.

For installing **tensorflow** just try this in command-line:

```
$ python -m pip install tensorflow
```

And if you get error for *no matching distribution* :

- Tensorflow only supports Python 3.5 to 3.8
- Tensorflow only supports 64-bit version of Python.

Check this and try again.